# How do I find a instance variable through its "actual" class?

Tags: class, oop, crystal-lang

The program I'm writing is storing elements in a hash called `grid` of type `Position => LivingBeing | Thing`. This `grid` is stored on a `Map` and I would like this `Map` to return the position of an element of class `Apple` which is a subclass of `Thing`.

However, when using `typeof()` to get the class, I get `LivingBeing | Thing` instead of the subclass `Apple`

Here is the `Map` class:

```
class Map
  @@grid = {} of Position => LivingBeing | Thing

  def initialize()
  end

  # Add an entity to the grid
  def add_entity(new_entity : LivingBeing | Thing)
    @@grid[new_entity.position] = new_entity
  end

  # Return the position of an object of class "something"
  def self.where_is?(something : Class)
    # First attempt was to get the key by the value
    # @@grid.key(something)

    @@grid.each do |position, thing|
      # Returns "thing #<Apple:0x55f1772085c0> at Position(@x=1, @y=2) is (LivingBeing | Thing)"
      puts "thing #{thing} at #{position} is #{typeof(thing)}"
      position if typeof(thing) == something
    end
  end
```

Here the `Thing` class:

```
abstract class Thing
  getter position
  @name = "Unkown object"

  def initialize(@position : Position)
  end
end

class Apple < Thing
  @name = "Apple"
end
```

Here the `Position` struct:

```
struct Position
  getter x, y

  def initialize(@x : Int32, @y : Int32)
  end
end
```

And here is the test I try to make it pass:

```
it "gives a random thing location based on its class" do
  world = Map.new()
  apple = Apple.new(Position.new(1, 2))
  puts "Apple type : #{typeof(apple)}" # Returns "Apple type : Apple"
  world.add_entity(apple)
  position = Map.where_is?(Apple)
  position.should eq Position.new(1, 2)
end
```

Is there some class method or function which could give the `Apple` class?
Or is it a design issue?

Thank you for your answer !

Comment: I need `Position` to compile your code, but does `return position if thing.is_a? something` solve your problem? As an aside, `typeof(foo)` returns the compile-time type, whereas `foo.is_a?` and `foo.class` operate at runtime.

Comment: I updated my question to add `Position` if you wish to compile the code. I tried to replace `position if typeof(thing) == something` with `position if thing.is_a?(something)`, but I get this error: `expecting token 'CONST', not 'something'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forall` to solve this:

```
  # Return the position of an object of class "something"
  def self.where_is?(something : T.class) forall T
    @@grid.each do |position, thing|
      return position if thing.is_a?(T)
    end
  end
```

and call it using `Map.where_is? Apple` just like you wish.

This works because the type variable `T` (introduced using `forall T`) can be inferred to be `Apple` from passing in the constant `Apple` which matches the `T.class` type restriction. `T` is then a constant you can use with `is_a?`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I have is this for my function:

```
  # Return the position of an object of class "something"
  def self.where_is?(something)
    @@grid.each do |position, thing|
      return position if thing.is_a?(typeof(something))
    end
  end
```

And this for the test:

```
  it "gives a random thing location" do
    world = Map.new(4)
    apple = Apple.new(Position.new(1, 2))
    world.add_entity(apple)
    position = Map.where_is?(Apple.new(Position.new(0, 0)))
    position.should eq Position.new(1, 2)
  end
```

I will use it like this if there is no other solution. But I would prefer to be able to search directly the class `Apple` instead of creating an instance of `Apple`

I would like to be able to do `position = Map.where_is?(Apple)` instead of
`position = Map.where_is?(Apple.new(Position.new(0, 0)))`

Answer (score 0):

As @ RX14 said, it looks like you want to check the run-time "type", i.e. `.class`.  Here's an example:

```
class Apple
  @name = "Apple"
end

def check(obj : Object)
  obj.class == Apple
end

a=Apple.new
p check(a)
```